# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: store_wishlist.user_id

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-jsonfield

I am working on ecommerce website. I wanted to implement wishlist function on my website. And, it is working if its the first time for user that is adding to the list. In the second time giving an error. What's the problem? Can someone please help me?
***views.py***

```
def addWishlistView(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print('Action:', action)
    print('Product:', productId)
    user = request.user
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)

    if (Wishlist.objects.filter(user=user) and Wishlist.objects.filter(product=product)).exists():
        print("Item is exists")
    else:
        Wishlist.objects.create(user=user,product=product)

    return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)
```

***models.py***

```
class Wishlist(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name="Название товара")
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
```

***script js***

```
for (i = 0; i < wishlist.length; i++) {
    wishlist[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var productId = this.dataset.product
        var action = this.dataset.action

        
        
        if (user == 'AnonymousUser'){
            Console.log("Not logged in");
        }else{
            addToWishlist(productId, action)
        }
    })
}

function addToWishlist(productId, action){
    console.log('User is authenticated, sending data...')

        var url = '/add_wishlist/'

        fetch(url, {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            }, 
            body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action})
        })
        
        .then((data) => {
            location.reload()
        })
}
```

Comment: Is the intention to allow a user to add multiple items to their Wishlist?

Comment: Yes, I it's only adding only one product per user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Wishlist.user` to a `models.ForeignKey` so that you can add multiple per user, you can add a unique constraint to the model to only allow a user to add a product one time using [Meta.unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

```
class Wishlist(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Название товара")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('user', 'product'),
        )
```

In your view you don't need your `if` block, you can use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) to only create a new entry if one doesn't already exist

```
    Wishlist.objects.get_or_create(user=user, product=product)
```

To delete a product from a user's wishlist if it exists or not you can use the [`delete()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#delete) method on a filtered queryset

```
    deleted = Wishlist.objects.filter(user=user, product=product).delete()
    if deleted == 0:
        # Can do something when nothing was deleted if you like
```

Comment: Wishlist.objects.get_or_create(user=user, product=product)

Comment: I had a question about this. how to delete then. If It's exists, I need to delete the item. I have no idea without if

Comment: I am sorry. But, Can I ask another question. I wanted to publish another question. It's saying that I need 90 minutes. How to know if the product is in wishlist while publishing?

Comment: @BehzodUrinov how to know if a product is in __any__ wishlists?

Comment: Yes, in my view I got all wishlist products that relate to this user. And, according to this, I want to know if the product in that while rendering products

Comment: @BehzodUrinov you want to render a list of products and add an annotation to each one that says if it's in the current user's wishlist or not?

Comment: Yes, I want to color a heart with red if it's in that

Comment: @BehzodUrinov might be worth asking another question. This answer is starting to get a bit messy as it is and the annotation you want is a little bit complex

Comment: I asked: Filter in the template if the product is in wishlist or no. Django ecommerce website